# Missing space around bold texts

Tags: spacing, bold, overleaf

I am trying to write a LaTex document on Overleaf with the XeLateX compiler. The generated pdf text should be copyable and pastable in a basic text editor and conserve its meaning and spacing.

However, for obscure reasons spaces are missing around my bolded text.

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}

This is a test and \textbf{this} is missing surrounding spaces 

\end{document}
```

[image: this is missing surrounding spaces]

When copied, I get this text:

```
This is a test and
this
is missing surrounding spaces
```

What should I do to get this result ?

```
This is a test and this is missing surrounding spaces
```

Many thanks.

Comment: (I'm on support staff at Overleaf.) Hi Namoz, I think this problem stems from one of the previewers we use. Sometimes different PDF viewers can have slightly different output when copying from the PDF. I'm going to check with some of our developers to see if this can be improved. But as a workaround for now, if you change to the "Native" PDF viewer you will see better results when copying text from the PDF: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Changing_PDF_viewer

Comment: @PaulGessler thank you for your quick answer. When using the native PDF viewer, there's no line break anymore. However, the text is still missing the spaces: "This is a test andthisis missing surrounding spaces"

Comment: In that case, can you write us at support@overleaf.com with your project's URL and the name and version of the browser you're using? Sorry for this hassle, there's a lot of variables at play here, and this will help us test to determine the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think it highly depends on the environment used. 
I tested the following using Tex-Live 2018 (using Texstudio editor) and the produced text can be copied without any issues.

```
%!TeX Program=xelatex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{cmap}
\begin{document}

This is a test and \textbf{this} is missing surrounding spaces 

\end{document}
```